# How to check the installed rosserial version

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Does anyone had any idea about how to check the rosserial version in the Ubuntu Kinetic? Because currently I'm trying to use rosserial to communicate with mbed, Due to some errors, the serial port will read failure.

Hope anyone can give some suggestion to help me. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246134/how-to-check-the-installed-rosserial-version/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried running `rosversion rosserial`?

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-10-21**:
it shows . so what's mean?

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2016-10-21**:
My bad, it seems that rosversion does not work for metapackages, so you would want to use `rosversion rosserial_arduino` or one of the other rosserial packages you might be using.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-10-21**:
wow~it work now! thank you so much!